# How to solve Rubocop respond_to_missing? offence

Tags: ruby, rubocop

Rubocop gives me the following offence

```
lib/daru/vector.rb:1182:5: C: Style/MethodMissing: When using method_missing, define respond_to_missing? and fall back on super.
    def method_missing(name, *args, &block) ...
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The method missing is defined as:

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  if name =~ /(.+)\=/
    self[$1.to_sym] = args[0]
  elsif has_index?(name)
    self[name]
  else
    super(name, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

I tried fixing it with the below code sighting an example from [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/always-define-respond-to-missing-when-overriding)

```
def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private=false)
  (name =~ /(.+)\=/) || has_index?(name) || super
end
```

But now Rubocop give me the follow offence:

```
lib/daru/vector.rb:1182:5: C: Style/MethodMissing: When using method_missing, fall back on super.
    def method_missing(name, *args, &block) ...
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. As you can see I'm falling back on super in the else block.

Comment: Put comments `# rubocop:disable Style/MethodMissing` before the line with offence and `# rubocop:enable Style/MethodMissing` just after. Rubocop is just a cop and it might make mistakes.

Comment: By the way: if you simply want to pass on the same arguments that you received, you can just call `super` without an argument list. This has nothing to do with your problem, which seems to be that Rubocop is simply not able to see that there is a path which leads to a `super` call (remember, static analysis of pretty much anything even remotely interesting is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem, and Ruby isn't exactly designed to be easily analyzable statically, to boot). Or, maybe, it actually *does* shut it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rubocop expects `super` to be called without arguments. As the arguments you are passing to `super` are the same as those you received, you can simply remove the arguments:

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  if name =~ /(.+)\=/
    self[$1.to_sym] = args[0]
  elsif has_index?(name)
    self[name]
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for getting in on this one @Justin. I think you might have identified another, missing cop. :-) Something along the lines of `Lint/UselessSuperArguments`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try `def respond_to_missing?(name, include_private=false)` instead?